# General rule for Django model class to always exclude "unpublished" instances

Tags: django

I'm searching a way to make some rule to exclude certain instances in each queryset. To follow DRY and to be sure that I(or some one else) will not accidentally include not accepted instances in queries. I'm relatively new in Djnago and didn't find the api to resolve this problem.

```
class SomeClassModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=244)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How could I(or some one else) exclude not accepted instances from all queries? Even if I do  `SomeClassModel.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ModelManager` and override the default `objects`, eg:

```
class ExcludeNotAccepted(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(accepted=False)

class SomeClassModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=244)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # make the default objects exclusive of non-accepted
    objects = ExcludeNotAccepted()
    # still allow explicit access via another name
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

This will have the desired effect of when accessing `SomeClassModel.objects.all()` of automatically filtering out non-accepted items, but you can still access all objects by explicitly using `SomeClassModel.all_objects.all()`...

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [**`Manager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager), and the override the `.objects` manager:

```
class AcceptedManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(accepted=True)
```

Then you can specify this `objects` manager, like:

```
class SomeClassModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=244)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AcceptedManager()
```

You can still access all the `SomeClassModel`s with `SomeClassModel._base_manager`, but you can evidently specify an extra manager:

```
class SomeClassModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=244)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AcceptedManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```